# Can I go to the B visa interview (USA) with a soon to expire passport?

Tags: visas, usa, passports

If I come from a country that is in the [Six-Month Club](https://www.cbp.gov/document/bulletins/six-month-club-update) (exempt from the 6 month rule), can I go to the B visa interview at the US embassy with a soon to expire passport? My passport has about a month left and my new passport is going to take a while but it will be ready for my travel. I know I can travel with both passports. I would like to avoid my visa being rejected.

More information here: https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html. Specifically I am trying to understand what this text means:

> (U) As passports issued by the countries listed in paragraph f below meet the requirements of INA 212(a)(7)(B)(i)(I) until the date shown for expiration, you could issue a visa at any time before that date.

Comment: It sounds like your current passport will expire before the trip, but in case your current passport does cover the trip, you might be good to go: https://www.cbp.gov/document/bulletins/six-month-club-update .

It says:
[...] Citizens of the countries listed below are exempt from the six-
month rule and need only have a passport valid for their intended period of stay [...]

Comment: @Alejandro my current passport will no longer be valid (expired) for the travel period.

Comment: @Alejandro also the title of the document says "Countries That Extend Passport Validity for an Additional Six Months After Expiration" would that work if that cover the travel period?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know for sure, anecdotally I can say that I once applied for a studies visa, did not realise my passport had 5 months and three weeks left and went to the interview, and was told to renew my passport immediately and had my interview bounced off to the next two days so I could come back with the new passport, and fortunately everything went well. In Mexico City, passports can be renewed in one day, if you're lucky enough to find an available time. I think you'll have to call the embassy to know for sure. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: @Alejandro was your visa rejected under [section 221(g)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html#:~:text=This%20means%20you%20are%20not,documentation%20are%20incomplete%20are%20refused.) ? In that case it makes sense that you were able to leave and combe back with an updated passport.

Comment: Nope, my visa was not denied or rejected, I was simply not interviewed that day, instead I was interviewed two days later, when I came back with the new passport. They might have made an exception because it was a student and not a tourist visa.

Comment: The next sentence following your quoted sentence says, "However, such action might not be practical when only a very narrow margin of time remains."

Comment: @Mauricio the six month extension only relieves travelers of the need to have a passport that expires at least six months after their anticipated departure; it means that the passport's expiration date only needs to be on or after the day of anticipated departure.  It does not allow people to enter the US after the expiration date.